# Conditionally set bash background/foreground color for a specific column/cell

Tags: linux, bash, git, colors, configuration

I want to configure bash so that a specific cell background is changed to a certain color.
The purpose is to use this color to act as a visual character count/ruler for ***git commit*** messages that are too long.

The color change is conditional.

It should happen ONLY when I am typing **git commit** messages. So the **first condition** is when I specifically type:

```
git commit -m
```

The **second condition** is that the color should appear ***'x'*** characters ***offset*** from the ***first*** 'quote' symbol (That indicates the beginning of the commit message etc).

The expected outcomes below use a **'Blue-R' emoji*** as a placeholder for the intended color change, in this case offset **50** characters from the first quote.

### Intended Outcome 1:

No line wrapping

```sh
user@linuxmint:~$ git commit -m 'My long and boring commit message over 50 charactes long'
```

### Intended Outcome 2:

Line wrapping

```sh
user@linuxmint:~/home/usr/directory/project/src$ git commit -m 'My long and bori
ng commit message over 50 charactes long'
```

How can I do this by modifying .bashrc? I am quite new to bash! I have played around with ANSI colors, but this is a bit above me right now!

Comment: Try to write a git hook, exactly a `commit-msg` hook that will print your commit message normal colour and change the background over given length.

Comment: Thanks @LéaGris I will investigate. Are these hooks able to run in real-time as you type, or only post commit?

Comment: It sounds like you're better off using a full editor for your commit messages, which is the default if you leave off the `-m` command-line option. Vim, for instance, will automatically apply syntax highlighting including this kind of long line detection. It's going to be *a lot* easier to customise that than to invent some kind of real-time command-line scanning.

Comment: I think that it is possible to do this *in bash*, but you would have to use readline hooks. It's also definitely the wrong way to go. You're much better off just using a good editor. Vim's default configuration normally recognizes `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` and sets up just what you want already, so you won't have to do anything except maybe tweak the preferred subject line length limit.

Comment: These are all great answers, and I realise it is easier to just use a text editor. But I like the Learning process so I’ll look into hooks as proposed, just to understand and play around with them! Hooks are new to me